How do I assign random colors to points?
How can I assign a random color to points created using the Mesh to Points node on the default cube? I found a similar problem but the user used the Instance to Points node and the solution provided doesn't work for me.
Here is the node setup

And the material setup

And finally, the output


Try switching the attribute domain to Point in the Store Named Attribute node, because you don't have instances here, but points.

Here's how you randomize color of your points and display it:

Store a named attribute in "Point" domain of "Color" type, and connect something to it, for example a "Random" node in "Vector" mode:


Remember to set the material and to use a different seed for color and position, otherwise it won't look random.

Use the same name of an attribute in your shader:



Use "Material Preview" or "Display Render" preview to see the effect of the material:



Thanks @StefLAncien - corrected.
